# Printing JSON array to screen via ajax to php script

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, json

I've been comparing my code to other examples on the web and I still can't find my errors. 
When I load the page and click submit, nothing happens on the screen. However, in Firebug I receive the `POST 200 OK` and the PHP script that should be on screen is spelled out in the POST response tab.

Since Firebug is responding appropriately, I am confused as to what is wrong.

Basic HTML form

```
<form id="form" action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
<div id="results"></div>
```

jQuery creates a JS object. The object is sent through `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`. The submit event handler fires off the `$.ajax`. JSON data is passed to `ok.php` and it should return the PHP info called in the script, in theory.

```
var addIt = new Object();

addIt.one = "one";
addIt.two = 2;
addIt.three = addIt.one +" + "+ addIt.two +" = "+ "three";

$jsonAddIt = JSON.stringify(addIt);
$jsonAddIt = JSON.parse($jsonAddIt);

$('#submit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ok.php',
        dataType:'json',
        data: ({ json:$jsonAddIt }),
        success:function(data) {
            $("#results").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
    $ajaxInfo = $_POST["json"];
    if ($ajaxInfo !="")
    {
        echo "info transfered"; 
    }
    else 
        echo "nothing";
?> 

<div id="returned">
    <?php print_r($ajaxInfo); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: what do u have when you alert the data variable in your success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two lines are not needed, the second one undoes the first one. just remove them both.

```
$jsonAddIt = JSON.stringify(addIt);
$jsonAddIt = JSON.parse($jsonAddIt);
```

This line should be giving you `[object Object]` in your div if the ajax request was successful, else it will do nothing (which is your current outcome).

```
$("#results").html(data)
```

Currently your ajax request is actually failing because it is not returning the expected JSON datatype. If you change your dataType to "html" it will work.

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: 'ok.php',
    dataType:'html',
    data: {json:addIt},
    success:function(data){
        $("#results").html(data);
    }
});
```

Also,

```
var addIt = new Object();
```

should be

```
var addIt = {};
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting the dataType to JSON will make jQuery ajax request to parse it automatically to a Javascript object. You have two solutions here. Either change the dataType of the ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
                     type:'POST',
                        url: 'ok.php',
                        dataType:'text',
                        data: ({json:$jsonAddIt}),
                        success:function(data){
                             $("#results").html(data);
                            }
});
```

Or you could use [this](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) library to stringify the object:

```
$.ajax({
                     type:'POST',
                        url: 'ok.php',
                        dataType:'json',
                        data: ({json:$jsonAddIt}),
                        success:function(data){
                             $("#results").html(JSON.stringify(data));
                            }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @aOviedo, I will look into adding the stringify the way you have mentioned. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is your `dataType`. By saying `json`, you're telling jQuery that the content you're expecting back is `json`. Where php is likely setting the content-type to html in the header. You should be able to remove that and jQuery will automatically figure it out from the header of the response.

Comment: Changing the datatype did help. Thanks for the info. +1